# Convert word document to excel

Tags: excel, csv, ms-word

I have a word document which needs to be converted to a table.

The catch however is, that the document contains a thousand pages and each page, needs to be an individual cell in the excel sheet. When I copy paste from Word, each line gets converted to one cell which i don't want. I need all the content between two page breaks to be a part of one cell.

To give some background on the issue, I need to basically create a csv from the the word file such that each page from the document is one value, hence I am trying to create a table.

Is there a way with which, this can be automated?

Comment: Whoa, a thousand page Word file needs to be converted with each page to be put in a cell? What are you going to do with that? The page can contain half of a paragraph of the preceding page, multiple paragraphs with multiple formats, half a paragraph that continues on the next page. And your criterion to write the Word content into Excel is how it displays on a Word "page"? Which is so totally printer dependent, it is not funny. What are you trying to achieve? Why "each page"? It would be a lot more sensible to do "each paragraph". At least that is a unit that does not depend on print drivers.

Comment: Hi,
I was basically trying to create a CSV to be imported into a wordpress blog. I found my solution on this link:

http://superuser.com/questions/747197/how-do-i-copy-word-tables-into-excel-without-splitting-cells-into-multiple-rows

Thanks anyways :).

Comment: The context of Wordpress helps a lot in understanding what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you could provide that "bigger picture" scenario in your future questions, so we know what you are aiming for. Glad you found a solution and +1 for taking the time and effort to post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my solution here :

https://superuser.com/questions/747197/how-do-i-copy-word-tables-into-excel-without-splitting-cells-into-multiple-rows

It basically involved replacing 'pilcrow' characters into my file for line breaks and doing vice versa in excel.

One important thing though, the article says to type 'alt+0010' (the key combination for line break) something while replacing pilcrows in excel. However, that did not work for me. Ctrl+J does the trick though, it inserts line break character in excel replace box.

Cheers :)